# A bookmarklet that reads source html for match then searches with google

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I already have a bookmarklet to extract an ID number from a page URL, that works perfectly - see below.

```
javascript:var%20q=document.location.href.match(/UserID=(.*?)(?=&|$)/i);{q=q[1];
window.open('http://google.com/search?q=street-scene+'+q);}
```

However I’m looking for a second bookmarklet that searches the html source code in a webpage to find an ID number and then search google for that number.

The piece of source code is below;

```
<p class="Padded" align="center">Link to this Profile using https://www.street-scene.com/4A416B62  or <span itemprop="url">
```

I’m looking to extract the 4A416B62 and search google for that ID, so the ID is between `www.street-scene.com/` and `. or <span itemprop=`

Are there any experts that can help, thank you?

Answer (score 1):

You need to be more specific when matching the id if you expect more text to follow it. Here I assumed you only need alphanumeric characters per identifier.
Readable:

```
var url = document.body.innerHTML.match(/https:\/\/www\.street-scene\.com\/([A-Z0-9]+)/i);
window.open("https://www.google.com/search?q=street-scene " + url[1]);
```

Bookmarklet:

```
javascript:window.open("https://www.google.com/search?q=street-scene "+document.body.innerHTML.match(/https:\/\/www\.street-scene\.com\/([A-Z0-9]+)/i)[1]);
```

I use [this resource](https://regex101.com) to test regular expressions, called Regex 101.
Your first bookmarklet redirects the user to a Google search involving a dash, which happens to be a search modifier. As far as I know, there is no way to preserve special characters when searching with Google.